# Android arraylist values are duplicating

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

```
    if(cursor.getCount() !=0)
    {

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                pObj.gritSize=cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("grit"));
                pObj.test = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("sieve"));
                pObj.number = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("number"));
                pObj.micro = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("micro"));
                pObj.ret = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("retention"));
                pList.add(pObj);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return pList;
```

I have the above code that fetches data from table. I am getting correct values in each iteration in pObj. But when i add pList.add(pObj); each time, it is overwriting the previous entry and adding the value. Hence at the end of the iteration i am getting last row as each item in the arraylist. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same object over and over. Try to create new object every time you iterate it.

On top of your `do` loop initialize it. For example;

`pObj = new YourClass();`

Answer (score 7):

Create a new instance for each iteration:

```
do {
     pObj = new YourObjectType();
     ....
} while (...);
```